# seperate() function in tidyverse in R

Tags: r

```
separate(data, col, into, sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+", remove = TRUE, convert = FALSE, extra = "warn", fill = "warn", ...)
```

`separate()` function is useful for split one column into columns.

I would like to use it to split a numeric column "time", containing values such as 20160903000000 and 20160903164030, where the first eight representing year, month day, and the rest representing the accurate time, like for 20160903164030, it represents year 2016, September 03, and 16:40:30.

Therefore, in order to manipulate the data, I have to get the year, month, and day.

The data is stored in the csv file,

I tried to use

`separate("time variable", into = c("year", "month", "day"), sep = c(4, 6, 8))`

to split this variable,

everything works fun, however, for 20160903000000, or every time record at 00:00:00, the separate function will consider it as 2.0160903 * 10^13, therefore the result of splitting it will be 2.01 year, 60 month, and 90 day, which is not correct.

Is there any way to make it be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, try reading in the date time columns as a date time column. You can use the readr package if you want to and specify the column classes.

Using `separate` can work, but to avoid issues, first transform it into a datetime column, then separate. Then you can just split on the "-" and the space that are in the date time column. See example below where I use `ymd_hms` function from lubridate as a step before using `separate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(x = lubridate::ymd_hms(x)) %>% 
  separate(x, into = c("year", "month", "day", "time"), sep = "-| ")

  year month day     time           y
1 2016    09  03 00:00:00 test record
2 2016    09  03 16:40:30 test record
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(2.0160903e+13, 20160903164030), y = c("test record", 
"test record")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```